# rpart function is overplotting or the desired partition is not achieved

Tags: r, machine-learning, rstudio

```
  ID Ethnicity MaritalStatus EmploymentStatus type
1 10         5             3                1    3
2 24         1             2                2    1
3 30         1             1                3    4
4 35         2             2                2    3
5 40         5             1                3    4
6 57         1             2                4    1
```

This is my sample data. the table has almost 94000 rows.
I tried the following command

```
m1 <- rpart(type ~ Ethnicity, MaritalStatus, EmploymentStatus, 
      data = table2, method = "anova")
```

My objective is to predict the 'type' based on the ethnicity, maritalstatus and emplymentstatus.
All the variables were converted into factor datatype using `as.factor()`
but the partition has taken place by ID, whereas I want the partition to happen by `Ethnicity`, then `MaritalStatus` and `EmploymentStatus`. I tried removing the `ID` column from the dataframe but the same problem exists.
I have attached an image of the results I get and also the corresponding rpart.plot [image: result]. 
Is my datatype or any basic approach to the data wrong?
I am a beginner to machine learning. I also tried by changing datatype of `ID` to numeric. 
Is there any way to set an hierarchy for partition?
 Why is the graph just a line?

[image: overplotted rpart plot]

Comment: Please make your example [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your formula. Predicting variables should be separated by `+`, instead of `,`. In your call, all but the first predicting variable (ethnicity) are ignored.

```
m1 <- rpart(type ~ Ethnicity + MaritalStatus + EmploymentStatus, 
      data = table2, method = "anova")
```